# Not revealing my MC's gender

Tags: gender, protagonist

I couldn't decide on whether the protagonist should be a girl or a boy. The MC's gender would just never be revealed and nobody would care about it, like in Undertale. Readers would barely question it because it's not important to the story.

So, uh... How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! The answers to the linked question should give you the advice you're looking for.

Comment: Just a comment: The linked Q&A is about keeping the gender ***purposely*** ambiguous. That is, the author makes a decision to keep *the reader* in the dark. If, as you say, *you* **cannot decide**, you should first figure out what gender you want or why you want to keep it ambiguous. Do not write from a point of being confused about the story you want to tell or your story might turn in to a confused mess.